# For que ordene por rangos

Tags: python, python-3.7

El problema es que tengo una lista de capítulos, una de temporadas y un rango.

```
capítulos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
temporadas [1,2,3]
rango[5,10,14]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que me diga a qué temporada pertenece cada capítulo, sabiendo que por ejemplo la temporada uno llega hasta el capítulo 5 (incluido), la temporada 2 hasta el 10... Y asi

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, al hacer preguntas es necesario que pongas también el código que tienes para ver lo que has intentado hacer. Puedes agregar lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1):

No sé para qué necesitas la lista de capítulos ni la de temporadas. Supongo que el problema se resuelve disponiendo nada más que la lista de rangos.

Por ejemplo, dada la lista de rangos `[5, 10, 14]` ¿a qué temporada pertenece el capítulo 7? Podemos responder perfectamente a esto, ya que la lista de rangos implica que los capítulos entre 0 y 5 son de la temporada 1, entre 6 y 10 de la 2, y entre 11 y 14 de la 3.

Podemos escribir una función que reciba un número de capítulo, la lista de rangos y te retorne a qué temporada pertenece. En el enunciado es un poco ambiguo a qué temporada pertenecería el capítulo 5. Se supone que sería parte de la primera, pero para hacer eso más explícito voy a incluir un parámetro en la función llamado `inclusive`, que valga `True` si se quiere incluir el 5 como parte de la primera sesión (en general, si los números en los `rangos` indican hasta qué capítulo llega la sesión *inclusive*).

La función sería así:

```
def que_temporada(capitulo, rangos, inclusive=True):
  for indice, r in enumerate(rangos, start=1):
    if capitulo in range(0,r+inclusive):
      return indice
```

### Como funciona

Se itera por el parámetro `rangos`. Al usar `enumerate()` cada iteración del `for` va a darnos dos números. El primero es el índice (comenzando en 1), por tanto la temporada que estamos considerando. El segundo `r` es el capítulo en que termina esa temporada.

Miramos si el  `capitulo` que estamos considerando está en el rango `(0, r+inclusive)` (suma 1 si `inclusive` es `True`, pues `range()` por defecto no considera el último valor). Si sale que está contenido, retornamos inmediatamente el valor de `indice`. Si no está contenido, pasamos al siguiente.

Si el bucle agota todo y no encontró nada, la función termina sin retornar nada, lo que es lo mismo que retornar `None`.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
rangos = [5, 10, 14]
for capitulo in [3, 5, 8, 13, 20]:
  print(f"El capítulo {capitulo} es de la temporada", que_temporada(capitulo, rangos))
```

produce:

```
El capítulo 3 es de la temporada 1
El capítulo 5 es de la temporada 1
El capítulo 8 es de la temporada 2
El capítulo 13 es de la temporada 3
El capítulo 20 es de la temporada None
```

## Ampliación

Para más generalidad y por si acaso las temporadas no se llaman 1, 2, 3... la siguiente versión de la función recibe otro parámetro con los nombres de las temporadas. El bucle es igual que antes, solo que ahora omito el `start=1` para que los índices comiencen en 0, y lo que retorna la función no es el índice, sino lo que encuentre en `temporadas[indice]` (el nombre de la sesión).

```
def que_temporada(capitulo, rangos, temporadas, inclusive=True):
  for indice, r in enumerate(rangos):
    if capitulo in range(0,r+inclusive):
      return temporadas[indice]
```

Ejemplo:

```
rangos = [5, 10, 14]
temporadas = ["S01", "S02", "S03"]
capitulo = 7
print(f"El capítulo {capitulo} es de la temporada", que_temporada(capitulo, rangos, temporadas))
```

produciría:

```
El capítulo 7 es de la temporada S02
```

Answer (score 0):

Itera por los rangos, luego por los capítulos y ve comprobando si el capítulo pertenece a ese rango:

```
capitulos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
temporadas = ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']
rango = [5, 10, 14]

out = {}
for i, x in enumerate(rango):
    out[temporadas[i]] = []
    for a in capitulos:
        if a <= x and (i == 0 or a > rango[i-1]):
            out[temporadas[i]].append(a)
```

o directamente usando list comprehension:

```
out = {temporadas[i]: [a for a in capitulos if a <= x and (i == 0 or a > rango[i-1])] for i, x in enumerate(rango)}
```